# SQLite copy data from one db to another using shell script

Tags: sqlite, scripting

How do you attach two sqlite db inside a shell script and script operations with their aliases?

for example: from the sqlite3 shell I can attach two different dbs, lets say db1 and db2, and then use:
insert into db2.table1(column1) select column1 from db1.table1;
to copy one column from a specific table on db1 to a specific table on db2.
but, how do I do that same inside a shell script?

Comment: Don't you know how to construct the SQL command strings, or how to give them to `sqlite3`?

Comment: I think I do,, I can do all I need from sqlite3 shell and I also can execute selects and inserts from a shell script,, but I havent found how to move data from a table on one db, to a table on another db, all from inside a shell script.

Comment: Show what you've got, and where you are stuck.

Comment: I thought I did.

Comment: I thought I did.
Let me see if I explain this again, I have the same table on two databases, one is filled with data, the other is empty. I want to move the data from one table to the other (notice they are on two different dbs),
If I do this from sqlite3 shell I follow this sequence:
1- attach database '/database1.db' as 'db1';
2- attached database '/database2.db' as 'db2';
3- .databases [this is just to check I have two aliases]
4- insert into db2.table1(column1) select column1 from db1.table1;
Then done,, I have all data on db1 copied to db2.
How to do the same on shell script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give multiple lines to the input of another program, you could redirect from a temporary file, or from a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
sqlite3 "" <<EndOfSqlite3Commands
ATTACH 'database1.db' AS db1;
ATTACH 'database2.db' AS db2;
INSERT INTO db2.table1(column1) SELECT column1 FROM db1.table1;
EndOfSqlite3Commands
```

Comment: Error: near line 4: near "EndOfSqlite3Commands": syntax error

Comment: I just put your suggestion inside a script, and ran it. and got the error above

Comment: My bad,, I put a ";" at the end,, by mistake. Testing the whole script now.